# Unsual behaviour in WiX 3.8 bootstrapper localization

Tags: wix, wix3.8

I have create an installer by using WiXBaStd and customize the UI by edit the theme.xml. Besides, I have apply localization in bootstrapper and set the thm.wxl(en-us) **Build Action** to **EmbeddedResource** and thm.wxl(ja-jp) to **None**.

Then when I run the bootstrapper.exe in JP OS, the **!(loc.ProductManufacturer)** and **!(loc.TransformsCode)** always be **EN-US** but the UI display Japanese !.

If I **reserve Build Action setting**, set the thm.wxl(ja-jp) **Build Action** to **EmbeddedResource** and thm.wxl(en-us) to **None**.

Then when I run the bootstrapper.exe in JP OS, the **!(loc.ProductManufacturer)** and **!(loc.TransformsCode)** always be **JA-JP** ! and UI display Japanese also !.

How come the **!(loc.ProductManufacturer)** and **!(loc.TransformsCode)** not being change correctly in localization ? How to solve this problem ? Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
  <?define ProductName = "Product A" ?> 
  <?define ProductManufacturer = "!(loc.ProductManufacturer)" ?>
  <?define ProductUpgradeCode = "AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA" ?> 

  <Bundle Name="$(var.ProductName)" Version="$(var.BuildVersion)" Manufacturer="$(var.ProductManufacturer)" UpgradeCode="$(var.ProductUpgradeCode)">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication SuppressOptionsUI="yes" LicenseFile="Localization\1033\LICENSE.rtf" ThemeFile="Custom\CustomRtfTheme.xml" />
      <Payload Name="1033\thm.wxl" SourceFile="Localization\1033\thm.wxl" />
      <Payload Name="1041\thm.wxl" SourceFile="Localization\1041\thm.wxl" />
      <Payload Name="1041\LICENSE.rtf" SourceFile="Localization\1041\LICENSE.rtf" />
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
    <Chain>
      <MsiPackage Id="MSI_A" SourceFile="A.msi">
        <MsiProperty Name="TRANSFORMS" Value="!(loc.TransformsCode)" />
      </MsiPackage>
      <MsiPackage Id="MSI_B" SourceFile="B.msi">
        <MsiProperty Name="TRANSFORMS" Value="!(loc.TransformsCode)" />
      </MsiPackage>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<WixLocalization Culture="ja-jp" Language="1041" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/localization">
  <String Id="TransformsCode">:ja-jp.mst</String>
  <String Id="ProductManufacturer">XXXXXX</String>
  <String Id="Caption">[WixBundleName] Setup</String>
  <String Id="Title">[WixBundleName]</String>
</WixLocalization>
```

Answer (score 0):

Localisation strings !(loc.whatever), and !(wix.variables) are applied by the binder at the end of the overall build process, after light.exe has completed linking the compiled objects.

This statement is a pre-processor statement so the payload is not available to be resolved at the pre-compile stage:
<?define ProductManufacturer = "!(loc.ProductManufacturer)" ?>

Comment: How would you localize !(wix.WixUILicenseRtf)?